# Visual Studio Code php in html

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code

How I can enable PHP syntax and PHP autocomplete in HTML files in vscode?

Default vscode can't see PHP in HTML files.

Answer (score 3):

The [PHP Intelephense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client) extension will forward requests to the vscode html language server when outside of `<?php ?>` and provide php intellisense when inside `<?php ?>` you must be in `php` language mode.

<sub><sup>*Disclaimer - I'm the author</sup></sub>

Comment: I have a file with 100% php, but with .html extension. Syntax highlighting and other features are not working. Is there a way to turn this on, or to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue when you mix match with html, php and js. They might fix. Meanwhile, you have to look for other tools. [issue -
 https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6616](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6616)

There are tools to do so. Search them on google.

One of that kind is

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HvyIndustries.crane

Comment: No. PHP intellisense I have, but he not support with html.

Comment: There is an issue when you mix match with html, php and js. They might fix. Meanwhile, you have to look for other tools. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6616